# Regular Expression Help - Difficulty Matching String

Tags: c#, regex

I need to match a string:-

- that always starts with 'P#' (case-insensitive)
- that always contains 'Z#'
- and ends with new line (\r or \n or \r\n)

Example strings:

- P#M1RE2Z#
- P#M2S0Z#M2SX0
- P#M3S12Z#

Here is what i figured out so far but need to match 'Z#' in between

```
(P#.*?(\r|\n|\r\n))
```

Comment: negative? whats wrong in this question?

Comment: @Druzion. I would appreciate you can suggest the appropriate title to the ESL guy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
\bP#(?=.*Z#)(?=.*[\r\n]+)\b
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yD7lH3/2)**

Comment: I have updated that link added some text around to be matched string

Comment: @user1327064 what you said was that it should start with `P#`..remove the anchor and it will work

Comment: @user1327064 good..remember it is only for matching and not storing the data

Answer (score 2):

this one should work for you

```
^P\#.*Z\#.*[\n\r]+
```

**Note:** I put \ before # because in regex # is comment,
this regex will much only if the line ends with \n or \r.

Comment: Thanks for help. But still not working for me. Check this link again. http://regexr.com/3d6kr

Comment: Look at this http://hpics.li/cfd12ec , I know your problem now you try to execute the regex on a text to get your matches but it won't work except with removing ^ from the beginning. http://regexr.com/3d6lj

Comment: @user1327064 your last link works fine - remove all sample text from the window, type your test text and press enter to create a CRLF.  The regex itself is fine.

Comment: Additionally, when using a test tool like regex101 or regexr, ONLY place the text that you want to verify in the text field.  Anything more than that can cause issues like this hat are difficult to troubleshoot if you are new to regular expressions.